# Y Axis and Y Field in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

What is Diff between `Y Axis` and `Y Field` in Wireshark IO Graphs.`Y Axis` has `AVG(YField)` Is it Average over all Packets or over Time.

Answer (score 0):

Y Axis is the AVG(YField) in the time interval you set (for example in the graphic below the time interval is 1 sec.

[image]